# How do I encrypt my home partition?

Tags: 10.04, encryption, home-directory

With Ubuntu 9.10 I did not have any encrypted partitions set up, I have since installed a fresh Ubuntu 10.04.

I have 3 partitions: OS root (`/`), `home` and `swap`. How do I enable encryption on my existing `/home` partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ubuntu Help: Encrypted Home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) points to this article here: [Migrating to an Encrypted Home Directory](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/06/migrating-to-encrypted-home-directory.html) which was written about a year ago. Though this article actually appears to still be valid in how to approach this.

You won't be encrypting the entire `/home` partition but rather each individual home folder. In future user setups you can pass the `--encrypt-home` flag on the useradd command. (`adduser --encrypt-home new-user-name`)