# How can I prevent someone from resetting my password with a Live CD?

Tags: security, password, live-cd

Recently one of my friends came over to my place, within 15 minutes he hacked my account using a Live CD and reset the password in front of me. I was baffled to see such a thing. Please guide me to prevent such a future attempt using a Live CD.

Comment: Unplug the optical disc drive.

Comment: It might interest you to know that it's possible to do the same thing in Windows; when I worked in IT at a large university, I had a CD with me to allow me to do so if needed.  No computer is really secure if one can boot from other media.

Comment: A hollow voice whispered "full disk encryption".

Answer (score 58):

Stand next to your computer while holding a tee-ball bat. Severely beat anyone who gets close.

Or lock it up.

If your computer is physically accessible, it is unsafe.

Comment: How does this protect us from the men with big dogs and machine guns? :D

Comment: secure computer with dogs and use security cameras to protect dogs and in next room motion-guns

Comment: +1 for the seriousness of this answer. You really did a good job here and deserve the votes.

Comment: +1 for the great answer and the comments.. I simply couldn't stop my self to laugh loudly!! :D :) @jrg was at his best.. ha ha ha.. :) Good to see this type thing in askubuntu.

Answer (score 56):

A quick and easy way to do this is to disable booting from CDs and USB sticks in your BIOS and set a BIOS password.

According to this [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2):

> Placing passwords or locking menu items (in the Grub configuration files) does not prevent a user from booting manually using commands entered at the grub command-line.

However there's nothing stopping someone from just stealing your hard drive and mounting it on another machine, or resetting your BIOS by removing the battery, or one of the other methods that an attacker can use when they have physical access to your machine.

A better way would be to encrypt your drive, you can either do this by encrypting your home directory, or encrypting the entire disk:

- [How do I encrypt my home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081/how-do-i-encrypt-my-home-partition)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto

Comment: That is not sufficient--you have to also disable recovery mode and lock down GRUB2 so that boot options cannot be specified (or cannot be specified without entering a password).

Once all this is done, not only does it not stop someone from stealing the hard drive, but someone who opens the computer can disable the BIOS password, and someone who doesn't want to open the computer can presumably just steal the whole computer.

Comment: but buddy what if someone just took my hard disk opened **/etc/shadow** changed my encrypted password and then rebooted the the encrypted home directory will also open for him

Comment: @shariq If someone changes your password just in /etc/shadow then the encrypted home directory will *not* open when someone logs on with the new password. In that case, the encrypted home directory would have to be mounted manually with the old password, and if nobody knew the old password, it would have to be cracked, which would be difficult and somewhat likely to fail. When you encrypt your home directory, changing your password by editing /etc/shadow does *not* change the password with which your data are encrypted.

Comment: @EliahKagan I can't any information on how to do that, so I've quoted the wiki page, if you find any more information feel free to edit it into my answer.

Comment: +1 The very first thing that came to my mind was encrypt the home directory.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I'm not sure why the Ubuntu Grub2 wiki page says that; according to http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Security, it seems that it's pretty easy to set up so that a password is necessary to access a GRUB2 command line. However, I'm reluctant to edit your answer myself right now, in case I'm missing something. If you (or another user knowledgeable about GRUB2) can confirm that my interpretation of that section of the official GRUB2 documentation seems right, then I'll go ahead and edit your post (or you could just edit your post after reading this, if you agree).

Comment: @EliahKagan I'll add a bounty when the system lets me to get it more attention. (I am not a grub expert)

Comment: I find when I put a password on my machines' BIOSes that I can easily circumvent it by pressing a key at the initial screen to bring up the hardware's own boot device manager. I also try encrypting my `/home` folder during installation, but I have no idea if that does anything for password security.

Comment: @EliahKagan, you can lock the computer to the desk or something with a steel wire connected to a Kensington Security Slot or other hoop on the chassis. You can also use `lm-sensors` to detect intrusions into the chassis and trigger a script that wipes cryptokeys and detonates explosives.

Comment: U can reset bios settings with set up password also with removing power and bios battery for 1min

Answer (score 28):

## First the warning...

The grub2 password protection procedure can be quite tricky and if you get it wrong there is a possibility of leaving yourself with a non-bootable system.  Thus **always** make a full image backup of your hard-drive first.  My recommendation would be to use *[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)* - another backup tool such as *[PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page)* could also be used.

If you want to practice this - use a virtual machine guest which you can rollback a snapshot.

## let's begin

The procedure below protects unauthorised editing of Grub settings whilst booting - that is, pressing <kbd>e</kbd> to edit allows you to change the boot options.  You could for example, force booting to single user mode and thus have access to your hard-disk.

This procedure should be used in conjunction with hard-disk encryption and a secure bios boot option to prevent booting from live cd as described in the associated answer to this question.

*almost everything below can be copied and pasted one line at a time.*

First lets backup the grub files we will be editing - open a terminal session:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/grub.d_backup
sudo cp /etc/grub.d/* /etc/grub.d_backup
```

Lets create a username for grub:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/00_header &
```

Scroll to the bottom, add a new empty line and copy and paste the following:

```
cat << EOF
set superusers="myusername"
password myusername xxxx
password recovery 1234
EOF
```

In this example two usernames were created: *myusername* and *recovery*

Next - navigate back to the terminal (don't close `gedit`):

**Natty and Oneiric users only**

Generate an encrypted password by typing

```
grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2
```

Enter your password you will use twice when prompted

```
Your PBKDF2 is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.D42BA2DB6CF3418C413373CD2D6B9A91AE4C0EB4E6AA20F89DFA027CA6E6CBF3542CB39E951607E9D651D82700AF47884929BDD193E36CB262CC96201B5789AA.1A9B0033928E3D3D0338583A5BF13AF7D5CC6EC5A41456F8FE8D8EBEB7A093CD0A0CE8688949E6007188ECB3FB0FF916F258602D130CF5C8525FB318FBBE2646
```

The bit we are interested in starts `grub.pbkdf2...` and ends `BBE2646`

Highlight this section using your mouse, right click and copy this.

Switch back to your `gedit` application - highlight the text "xxxx" and replace this with what you copied (right click and paste)

i.e. the line should look like

```
password myusername grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.D42BA2DB6CF3418C413373CD2D6B9A91AE4C0EB4E6AA20F89DFA027CA6E6CBF3542CB39E951607E9D651D82700AF47884929BDD193E36CB262CC96201B5789AA.1A9B0033928E3D3D0338583A5BF13AF7D5CC6EC5A41456F8FE8D8EBEB7A093CD0A0CE8688949E6007188ECB3FB0FF916F258602D130CF5C8525FB318FBBE2646
```

**all 'buntu versions (lucid and above)**

Save and close the file.

Finally you need to password protect each grub menu entry (all files that have a line that begins *menuentry*):

```
cd /etc/grub.d
sudo sed -i -e '/^menuentry /s/ {/ --users myusername {/' *
```

This will add a new entry `--users myusername` to each line.

Run update-grub to regenerate your grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

When you try to edit a grub entry it will ask for your user name i.e. *myusername* and the password you used.

Reboot and test that username and password is being enforced when editing  all of the grub-entries.

N.B. remember to press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> during boot to display your grub.

**[Password protecting recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31605/how-to-secure-grub-recovery-mode)**

All of the above can easily be workaround by using recovery mode.

Fortunately you can also force a username and password to use the recovery-mode menu entry.  In the first part of this answer we create an additional username called *recovery* with a password of *1234*.  To use this username we need to edit the following file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/10_linux
```

change the line from:

```
printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
```

To:

```
if ${recovery} ; then
   printf "menuentry '${title}' --users recovery ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
else
   printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
fi
```

When using recovery use the username *recovery* and the password *1234*

Run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate your grub file

Reboot and test that you are asked for as username and password when trying to boot into recovery mode.

---

More Information - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1369019

Comment: Hi! I followed your tutorial and it works... except if you choose other versions, where you can use "E" key without password

Comment: Raring doesn't have the line `printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"` for recovery but a similar one inside an if function. Could you advice how to edit it?

Comment: Is uncommenting the line `#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"` in `/etc/default/grub` an alternative to password protecting recovery mode?

Answer (score 6):

It's important to remember that if someone has physical access to your machine, they will always be able to do things to your PC. Things like locking your PC case and BIOS passwords won't stop a determined person from taking your hard drive and data anyway.

Comment: In some circumstances, these things *will* stop even a determined person from taking your hard drive and data way. For example, if it is a kiosk machine in an Internet cafe with good physical security (security cameras, security guards, watchful proprietor/clerks), a determined person might still try to physically steal the machine or its hard drive, but they would likely fail.

Comment: As a separate point, if you steal the hard drive from a machine whose data are encrypted, then you would have to crack the encryption to access the data, and with good quality passwords, doing so might be prohibitively difficult...or perhaps even impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need:

- The most important: Full disk encryption with luks. This protects hardware storage extraction and boot to external CD-ROM/USB attacks. Encrypting home directory is not sufficient.
- Set BIOS password. This is important because /boot is still unencrypted, and more important when you store passwords in TPM.
- Optional: set GRUB password.

Answer (score -2):

You can make it so that even in a case of resetting, the "resetter" wont be able to see the data.

To do this, just encrypt `/home`.

If you want to make it so that resetting isn't possible, something needs to be removed, which is in charge of changing the password.

Comment: Access to your personal files isn't the only concern. If, say, your account has `sudo` privileges, they don't need `/home` to do major damage.