# How to allow local logins, after misconfiguring PAM in AD integration process

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, active-directory

**Aim:** Create an R server that integrates into our Windows environment by setting up AD integration on an Ubuntu box

**Using:** Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**Following:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto

**Problem:** An ubuntu server was provisioned for me, and I was given a login ruser. I've been following the AD integration walkthrough and then applied this section of the how-to

> file: /etc/pam.d/common-auth
>   auth sufficient pam_winbind.so auth
>   sufficient pam_unix.so nullok_secure use_first_pass auth required
>   pam_deny.so
>
> On a Ubuntu 7.10 (Gutsy Gibbon) and 9.04 (Jaunty
>   Jackalope) systems, these changes to pam.d/common-auth result in not
>   being able to log in as a local user, for example by ssh. Your luck
>   may be better, but test immediately just in case.

and then scrolled down to find out that this prevents logins from local accounts, around the same time my PuTTY session shut down and attempting to login again now results in the session being shut down.  I can use an AD login to get in but cannot amend the common-auth file with my AD login as I'm not in the sudoers group.

**Requirement:** If root is disabled is there another way I can change the file now that I've locked myself out?

Comment: root can still log in; if you don't know the password but have access to the physical machine boot into single user mode, or chroot in from a live CD.

Comment: Dang, root is disabled and it's a virtual.  I'm getting a restore from backup as it doesn't seem like this is fixable.  A solution though for silly folks like me who manage this in future would be awesome.

Comment: Sorry, I was surprised you could [disable single user mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186176/how-to-disable-recovery-mode-single-user-mode).  At this point your only bet is to boot the virtual machine off of an image, but my guess is your admin disabled that as well, so you'll have to go to them for help.

Comment: Virtual restored from image, added a domain group to sudoer list and then did PAM config.  Thanks @virtualxtc