# GRUB 2 - Avoid unrestricted boot options are overwritten with kernel updates

Tags: boot, grub2, password

I have all my grub options protected by password excepting the default Ubuntu option. This is done by adding "--unrestricted" to the boot option in /boot/grub/grub.cfg as explained here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Password_protection_of_GRUB_edit_and_console_options_only

The problem is each time grub2 is updated the "--unrestricted" parameter disappears and I have to add it again. Is there any way to make this permanent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit the scripts that *generate* `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, not that file itself.

For the Ubuntu entry, check out `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and search for the lines that output `menuentry`. The relevant part on my system looks like this:

```bsh
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  else
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi
```

I think the first of those (with `echo "$title"`) should be used for all "Advanced options" whereas the second line (with `echo "$os"`) seems to be responsible for the "normal" Ubuntu entry.

You can insert additional options in here, so that the correct `menuentry` line gets printed as you want it to appear in the `grub.cfg` file.

Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards to regenerate the config from your changed scripts.

Other related posts:

- [How to set up GRUB2 password in an easy way?](https://askubuntu.com/q/499264/367990)
- [Seeking for a better solution to restrict access in GRUB2 menu](https://askubuntu.com/q/356244/367990)

Comment: Ok! If I put "--unrestricted" just before ${CLASS} in those 2 lines, will it affect only default boot option, or all boot options?

Comment: Good question. From examining the scripts and output more closely, I think the first of those (with `echo "$title"`) should be used for all "Advanced options" whereas the second line (with `echo "$os"`) seems to be responsible for the "normal" Ubuntu entry.

Comment: I tested and it works! Now only the default Ubuntu menu entry can boot without password, the other menu entries, "edit" and "console" stay password protected :)