# How do I disable root password reset via GRUB edit?

Tags: permissions

I want to completely disable resetting root password! Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: See [fossfreedom's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78051/22949) to [How can I prevent someone from resetting my password with a Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76987/how-can-i-prevent-someone-from-resetting-my-password-with-a-live-cd) That answer addresses your specific question--how to prevent people from editing boot options with GRUB to produce a root shell on boot--and some of the other answers address the other aspects of protecting a machine's password from users with (a constrained but significant degree of) physical access, including the limitations inherent in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to prevent people with access to your computer from changing your root password, you can encrypt your entire Ubuntu partition so that other people cannot boot your installation of Ubuntu **at all** without knowing the password to the partition.

This is because once somebody has physical access to your computer, there is no way (at least of that I can think of) to prevent that other than to have your root partition encrypted.

Comment: IMO encryption is the best method, but, be warned, even with an encrypted install / boot is NOT ENCRYPTED. The encryption can be cracked if one has physical access either with a key logger (no all ke loggers are external) or by installing a custom kernel or custom initrd. IMO one MUST LIMIT PHYSICAL ACCESS.

Comment: You can partially work around that by using hardware-based full disk encryption solutions, but the point about keyloggers still stand.